# scheme - building own evaluate procedure

Tags: function, lambda, scheme, racket

I am trying to build an evaluating procedure in scheme for school. It requires its own environment, built as lists. for example

`(define env (list
             (list 'x 5)
             (list '+ +)
             (list '* *)))`

where when called with the function

```
 (define lookup
   (lambda (symbol  env)
     (cond [(not (symbol? symbol)) 0]
          [(null? env) 0]
          [(eq? symbol (car (car env))) (car (cdr (car env)))]
          [else (lookup symbol (cdr env))])))
```

we can get procedures and values from symbols. What I need help with is the evaluating function which takes a list like     `'(+ 1 x)`     it will look at the symbol     `'+`     and find that it is evaluated to the addition procedure using lookup, and then applying the procedure to the everything else in the list. So far I have

```
(define evaluate
   (lambda (expr env)
     (cond [(null? expr) 0]
           [(number? (car expr)) ((car expr) (evaluate (cdr expr) env))]
           [(procedure? (lookup (car expr) env)) ((lookup (car expr) env)
                                                 (evaluate (cdr expr) env))] `
```

What I have trouble with is applying the procedure every time the function goes through recursion. How can I apply say the addition to every element of the list? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It matters *a lot* how much error-handling you intend to do. In the most trivial case, where you assume all expressions have the correct arguments, it is just something like

```
(let ((op (lookup (car exp))))
  (apply op (cdr exp)))
```

Comment: Thank you, since it is for school, all expressions will have the correct arguments

Comment: So if `expr` is `(* (+ 4 5) 2)` how is this supposed to "work"?

Comment: @Sylwester perhaps I misunderstood the question. It looks like he understood `evaluate`-ing the `cdr` but missed understanding the `apply` part.

Answer (score 0):

`lookup` shouldn't really care if you don't pass a symbol. Just check `(eq? symbol (car env))` as long as `env` is not null. Since all expressions have correct arguments it should never hit null so I would expect `(error "should never happen")` as a good result in that case.

`evaluate` doesn't handle the simple expressions. Why? eg.

```
(evaluate 5 '()) ; ==> 5
```

Why is `(evaluate '() '()) ; ==> 0`? it doesn't make sense. In many lisps it's self evaluating, but I guess in your evaluator that handles math it isn't a valid expression. These are:

```
(evaluate 'x '((x 5))) ; ==> 5
```

Now for the actual compose default case:

```
(evaluate '(+ x y) '((x 5) (y 7)))
```

This should do:

```
(apply (eval '+ env)
       (evlis '(x y) '((x 5) (y 7)))
```

And `evlis` is a procedure you need to make that takes a list an evaluates each element using the provided environment. Thus the above turns into:

```
(apply + '(5 7))
```

The whole point by doing this is that this should work:

```
(* (+ 4 5) 2) ; ==> 18
```

This works because you evaluate each part and since you evaluate each part it will also evaluate its parts. `eval` is inherently recursive.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! it's helpful to see where the program should get errors, I had it set to 0 if to see if the program would recurse back and look for a final value to add, so now I get that I should add an error in the case where the environment had nothing.